# How to make the radio button clickable on text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

My text can not be clickable

Given I put my input inside the label tags

html code

```
            <label for="mvaas_api_log_server_information"><input checked="checked" id="server_information_portal" name="server_information" type="radio" value="portal">
            portal
            </label>
            <label for="mvaas_api_log_server_information"><input id="server_information_register" name="server_information" type="radio" value="register">
            register
            </label>
          </div>
```

haml code

```
        = f.label "Choose Server" , class:'col-sm-2 control-label no-padding-right', for: 'form-field-1'
        .col-sm-5
          - %w(portal register).each_with_index do |server_type, i|
            = f.label :server_information do
              - if server_type == @mvaas_api_log.server_information
                = radio_button_tag :server_information, server_type, true
              - else
                = radio_button_tag :server_information, server_type
              = server_type
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` attribute of the label must match the `id` of the input you want to trigger, like this:

```
<label for="server_information_portal"><input checked="checked" id="server_information_portal" name="server_information" type="radio" value="portal">
        portal
        </label>
        <label for="server_information_register"><input id="server_information_register" name="server_information" type="radio" value="register">
        register
        </label>
      </div>
```

If the `for` attribute doesn't match, the browser has no way of knowing what input the label goes with.